# What is a HtmlTokenizer?

Tags: c#, html, tokenize

What does a HtmlTokenizer really do?

What is its utility ?

How can I use it in a C# application ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It parses html and exposes the tags (and their data and attributes), using a 'listener' style interface similar to SAX for XML. Although I beleive there are quite a few different implementations of classes called HTMLTokenize.

The listener style output works by calling methods in the listener when the parser encounters certain elements, for example you may have a startTag(...) method in the listener, and whenever the parser encounters the start of a new tag it will call this method and pass in data for the tag found. Similarly when the end of the tag is encountered it will call a coresponding endTag() method. It is up to the listener to keep track of exactly what and where the parsing is up to, which is why often a parser that simple exposes a DOM tree is easier to use.

If you can provide mode specifics on where this class comes from, more detail can be then provided in an answer.
Also, I am not aware of any C# class libraries that have this class, only Java??

Answer (score 3):

It converts HTML elements to tokens, like this:

```
<div><b>Tekst!</b></div>
```

This can be converted to something like this:

```
TOKEN_DIV TOKEN_STRONG TOKEN_STRING TOKEN_END_STRONG TOKEN_END_DIV
```

With this, you can create a parser that will parse the document.

Comment: A parser-error will occur; for example, if this tokens are found: TOKEN_DIV TOKEN_STRING, you see that TOKEN_END_DIV isn't there. Each HTML token needs a closing token. If that's not the case, then the error will occur.

Comment: It should throw some kind of ParseException... But this is quite different to the tokenizer i once used - forget the package, but was as per my answer.

Comment: I need something exactly that does this, is something available for PHP or Javascript?

Answer (score 1):

A HTML tokenizer simply breaks a stream of text into tokens, where each token is a string. 
Normally each string represents either "text", or an HTML element.

You can use it in c# like any other class.